# $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (f_n+g_n)$ converges uniformly to $f+g$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

If $\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty g_n(x)$ converges uniformly to $g$, then $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (f_n+g_n)$ converges uniformly to $f+g$.

*This seems true to me but I can't find anything in my book about it.*

Comment: Any thoughts about what $\left|\sum_{n=0}^N f_n(x) + \sum_{n=0}^N g_n(x) - f(x) - g(x) \right|$ might tell you?

Comment: The least upper bound of $S$.

Comment: Using the triangle inequality you can bound  $|\sum (f_n+g_n) - (f+g)|$ in terms of $|\sum f_n - f|$ and $|\sum g_n - g|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\{f_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$, $\{g_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$are functions from $D$ to $\mathbb{R}$ which converge uniformly to $f$ and $g$ respectively. let $\varepsilon >0$ and $x\in D$.

Since $g_n$ converges uniformly to $g$ and $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$, there exists $M, N$ such that for all $x\in D$, $|f_m(x) -f(x)| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ for all $m\geq M$ and $|g_n(x)-g(x)| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ for all $n\geq N$. Now for all $n > max(M,N)$ $|f_n(x)-f(x)| + |g_n(x)-g(x)| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}+\frac{\varepsilon}{2} = \varepsilon$.

Consider the following:
\begin{align}
|(f_n+g_n)(x) - (f+g)(x)| &= |f_n(x)-f(x) +g_n(x)-g(x)| \\
&\leq |f_n(x)-f| + |g_n(x)-g(x)| \\
&<\varepsilon
\end{align}

Now, $|(f_n+g_n)(x)-(f+g)(x)| <\varepsilon$ for all $x\in D$ so that $f_n+g_n$ converges to $f+g$ uniformly.